# Cannot enable strong name verification skipping on Server 2012

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Lost sources for a signed dotnet assembly.
Getting the infamous: Strong name validation failed error "0x8013141A" on Windows Server 2012.

Tried to enable verification skipping but the system keeps reporting the failed validation error.

Steps taken:

Running the **sn.exe -Vr *,*** command tool (both x32 and x64) added the following registry keys:

**HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\StrongName -> *,*
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\StrongName -> *,***

Works perfectly on the development Win 8.1 / VS 2013 machine, but Windows Server 2012 seems to ignore the registry keys.

Also checked access for the user account running the application to the registry keys which indicates read access.

**Scoured the internets for days now, any insights are highly appreciated?**

Perhaps another way to disable the verification check?

Answer (score 0):

Self answer. 
Executable had a config file containing:

```
<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="false"/>
```

It appears to take precedence...